# Ldap configuration on xammp

Tags: php, ldap, xampp

I have been trying to configure ldap on xammp localhost.

I have enabled ldap extension in php.ini file.

I have also tried to change the system variables.

I have been continuously getting this error

LDAP functionality not present. Either load the module ldap php module or use a php with ldap support compiled in.

Any help is welcomed

Comment: Did you edit the CORRECT .ini file? PHP has multiple .ini's. Check `phpinfo()` to see which file(s) it's using. Did you restart the server after modifying the .ini?

Comment: When I restart the xampp it gives this error PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_ldap.dll

Comment: so you've got a .dll that's not the correct version, or compiled for a different version of php, most likely.

Answer (score 7):

I've found this solution and it works for me:

"I have copied the "libsasl.dll" from the "xampp/php" directory into the "xampp/apache/bin" directory, uncommented the "extension=php_ldap.dll" in "xampp/php/php.ini", and started Apache."

I found it in https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=48302#p186324